# How to add values in HTML forms?

Tags: html, forms

How would i add the "value" that are selected from radio boxes in html forms? So when someone selects an option it would add the other "values" onto it and total that it at the bottom of the page. And does anyone know if it could add "names" total "values" onto it as well? thanks

My code looks like this:

```html
<h3><u>Title</u></h3><br>
 <form action="">
 <input type="radio" name="num" value="0">Text<br>
 <input type="radio" name="num" value="2">Text<br>
 <input type="radio" name="num" value="80">Text<br>
 <input type="radio" name="num" value="110">Text<br>
 <input type="radio" name="num" value="85">Text<br>
 <input type="radio" name="num" value="120">Text<br>
 </form>
```

Comment: I'm not 100 percent sure, but I think what you need is javascript.

Comment: What the... what do you want to happen when one selects an option?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. By definition, a set of radio buttons with the same `name` attribute contributes at most one value to the data set, the one corresponding to the selected button.

If you want something else, you should handle that server side, or use other types of controls, or redesign the entire approach.

Answer (score 0):

**Working example :**

(using a Javascript library, jQuery, but could be done in plain JavaScript)

*You mainly have to change your inputs to `type="checkbox"` in the HTML*

What code does : when a checkbox's state is modified, all checked checkboxes' value are summed up in the last input field I've added

The checkboxes are targetted by looking for "num" in their name, if you remove that the checkbox won't be taken into account by the script.

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[name*='num']").on("change", function() {
    var total = 0;
    $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
      total += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $("#total").val(total);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>
    <u>Title</u>
</h3>

<br>

<form action="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="num0" value="0">Add 0<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="num2" value="2">Add 2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="num80" value="80">Add 80<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="num110" value="110">Add 110<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="num85" value="85">Add 85<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="numwhateveryoulike" value="120">Add 120<br>
  Total <input type="text" value="0" id="total">
</form>
```